# Laravel Validator: limiting unique field check to specific product

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to make a unique validator to check against a specific product. Like:

```
// Validate Request for name and url
$this->validate($request, [
    'nome' => 'bail|required|min:2|unique:produto,name',
    'url'  => 'required|unique:produto',
]);

// Grab the user->id
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;

// Create a new product
if ($product = Product::create([
    'user_id'   => $user_id,
    'name'      => $request['nome'],
    'url'       => $request['url'],
    'is_active' => $request['is_active'],
])) {
    flash()->success('Produto criado.');
} else {
    flash()->error('Não foi possivel criar produto.');
}

// Check if $request data is unique at above created product
$this->validate($request, [
    'addmore.*.plataforma' => 'required|unique:plataforma_produto,plataforma_id,' . $product->id . ',id,product_id',
]);

// For each of the addmore.*. fields create an entry on DB
foreach ($request->addmore as $value) {
    Plataformaprod::create([
        'product_key'          => $value['product_key'],
        'basic_authentication' => $value['basic_authentication'],
        'codigo_produto'       => $value['codigo_produto'],
        'plataforma_id'        => $value['plataforma'],
        'product_id'           => $product->id,
    ]);
}

return redirect()->route('products.index');
```

Checking the comments inside my code its basically doing this:

- Validate `$request` for name and url
- Grab the `user->id`
- Create a new product
- (this is what I can't get to work) **RUN THE UNIQUE RULE JUST AGAINST A SPECIFIC PRODUCT_ID AND CHECK IF IT HAS UNIQUE PLATAFORMA_ID ENTRIES!**

Comment: "I can't get to work" any error you get or what?

Comment: Please show the error you get.

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't make the validation rule to work properly so I found this solution:

- Created a unique index between the product_id and plataforma_id inside my migration file.
- Created a try catch encapsulating the hole store method.
- Catch the $e and turn it to a 500 error message saying: "The product already have a plataforma_id with that ID. Just added the first
  record, change it's info in Edit page. It this error persists contact
  dev@"